# One Spring Boot project, deploy to both JAR or WAR

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

Is there a way to have a single Spring Boot project be packagable into both JAR and WAR without changing the `pom.xml` or the application source?

I've read [Converting a Spring Boot JAR Application to a WAR](http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/), but it **converts** the project to WAR and it loses the ability to be packaged as JAR.

I don't expect `mvn package` to do both. What I want is something like `mvn i-want-a-jar` and it would package the project as JAR. Or I could run `mvn i-want-a-war` and it would package the project as WAR.

Is this possible?

Comment: not in the same project no.

Comment: I empathise with this question.  I spent an hour trying to make my executable-jar work before I realized I could just use the executable WAR fine; everyone kept saying executable JAR in docs so I thought I needed one :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What's wrong with a WAR file that's executable? Isn't that what you really need?

P.S. like
`java -jar name.war`

Comment: How do I execute a Spring Boot WAR file with `java -jar name.war`? When I try it with the Hello World example I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hello/Application`

Comment: Never mind that, looks like I forgot to include `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. `java -jar name.war` worked after I included it.

Answer (score 43):

I managed to do it by adding

```
<packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>
```

to the POM file and then setting different profiles for JAR and WAR:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>jar</id>
      <properties>
        <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>war</id>
      <properties>
        <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
      </properties>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Now `mvn package -P war` produces a WAR and `mvn package -P jar` produces a JAR.

Another option is to create separate modules for JAR and WAR, but I didn't go that route.

Comment: What will happen by default when you run mvn package?

Comment: Add `<activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>` to the profile that you want to run as the default one, so you don't have to set the `-P` flag.

Comment: Alternatively, it seems to be OK to add a default setting for `packaging.type` in the main pom.xml's `<properties>` section.

Answer (score 5):

We've recently had a similar requirement, where an existing Spring Boot based project that was originally packaged as an executable Jar needed to support Tomcat and WildFly deployments.

Due to some dependencies used in this project (for example WebJars), a simple switch to WAR package wasn't an option since some of those dependencies were required for WildFly (VFS support) but not for other deployment.

The solution was to restructure the project modules in a way that *core* module contained the actual project but without having Spring Boot’s plugin applied, while several *package* modules would depend on *core* module and configure deployment artifact specifics (Boot and other plugins, deployment specific dependencies etc.).

That way project build was able to generate multiple deployment artifacts (Boot's executable JAR, traditional WAR and WildFly specific WAR) in a single build run.

In case anyone finds this useful, the sample project to demonstrate the approach is [available on Github](https://github.com/vpavic-demos/spring-boot-multi-package-demo). The project can be built by either Gradle or Maven.

Comment: This is what I am looking for but my project is maven based. I need your help for this in maven based structure. Can You please update your Github repo for maven based projects.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated the project to also include support for Maven build.

Comment: Thanks, By the way on side note: Is not this can be achieved by profiles of maven?

Comment: I'm not a fan of that solution - if I'm building a product that needs to support multiple deployment environments, I'd like to have all artifacts produced by a single build run. From a CI or release build standpoint, it's also preferable to have a single build.