# How to make SpringBoot project run through war package, and can also run through jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I want my project to be launched on my personal computer via the Main function (either via `java -jar` or by `mvn spring-boot: run`), and when the development is complete, I can deploy it directly to Tomcat.
How to configure, to do this

Comment: the answer I really want is here: [One Spring Boot project, deploy to both JAR or WAR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25102040/8251835)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special. Just [follow the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) to build a deployable war. The war file created using the Spring Boot build process is executable as a regular jar file as it contains an embedded servlet container in a separate directory called `lib-provided` which is added to the classpath only when the war is directly executed.

Bonus: If you want to get rid of unnecessary dependencies on embedded server when creating a deployable war, you can check out [a blog post](http://dolszewski.com/spring/dual-jar-war-build-for-spring-boot/), which show how to do it step-by-step.

Comment: Thank you. You helped me learn more, but the answer I really want is here: [One Spring Boot project, deploy to both JAR or WAR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25102040/8251835)@Daniel Olszewski