# Spring boot application build as WAR and JAR at a time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot version 2.1.1 and build tool as Gradle, I would like build the application as WAR and JAR at once. How would i do that?

Comment: Have you taken a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868580/one-spring-boot-project-deploy-to-both-jar-or-war

Comment: I would also add what kind of jar (executable/shaded jar) or war(deployable in tomcat, or executable) do you want.

Comment: I am using JAR in spring boot project. you can choice.

Comment: That's not possible to have it at once because you can have only one artifact at a time. I'm not a Gradle user but with Maven you would do so using Maven profiles and call the build twic.e